# css gradient up to down and right to left problem

Tags: html, css

I hope mybackground can like this
[image]
It has two color and color would lighter at top and deeper in bottom,
this is my css :

```
body{
 width: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(0.25turn, #FFE53B 14.93%, #FF8329 40.29%, 
#ebf8e1, #24DD40 15.83%, #B9FF00 51.21%);

}
```

My css have two color, but it is left to right ,the color left is deep and right is light,but this is not my want....
I don't know how to revise it.(I just can use one box not two，so I do not know how to slove it...
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>

        #one {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #one:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to top,  #FF8329  0%, #FFE53B  100%), linear-gradient(180deg, #B9FF00  0%, #24DD40 100%);
            background-position: top left, top right;
            background-size: 50% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="one"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can try this, I have divided the page into two div's and have given bg color to them.

Comment: Let me know if you need any other help!

Comment: Nikhil Singh I have some reason , so I have to use one box not two, can I use one box to do this? thanks

Comment: So you want to achieve the same result with one div, right ?

Comment: Nikhil Singh ,yes

Comment: On it, @samurai!

Comment: I have updated the code @samurai!

Comment: thanks, but it still two box, and I have try use two box, but it would have margin....I have set margin{0) ,but it still no use whem I add <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> on my header

Comment: I have used just one div! I didn't get you what do you mean by two box

Comment: And for bootstrap, you need to add `class="container-fluid"` to the wrapper container div in order to have no margin or padding and allow it to cover the entire screen.

Comment: Nikhil Singh my data was not update, now I see it,I would try ,thanks

Comment: Perfect @samurai! Hope that helps :)

Comment: I am glad, was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you make an absolutely positioned element that holds the background image, like so:

```css
body {
  position: relative
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.background__left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( #FFE53B, #FF8329);
}

.background__right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( #B9FF00, #24DD40);
}

main { 
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="background__left"></div>
    <div class="background__right"></div>
  </div>
  <main>
    <div class="filler" style="width: 100px;height: 100px">Main content</div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href = './flex.css' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

body div {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    top:  0;
    bottom: 0;
}

body div:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0;
    background:linear-gradient(to top,  #FF8329  , #FFE53B );
}

body div:nth-child(2) {
    right: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to top,  #24DD40 , #B9FF00 );
}
```

I have divided the body into two `divs` Also I have set `position: absolute` so U can add content above them.

Comment: Mauj Mishra, I have some reason , so I have to use one box not two, can I use one box to do this? thanks